# Configure cake bake to enable cascading delete

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cake-bake

I am using cakephp v3.3.3

After using cake bake to auto-generate code, I have this php file BallsTable.php which has the initialize() function below;

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('balls');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Baskets', [
        'foreignKey' => 'basket_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('BallRecords', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ball_id',
    ]);
}
```

However, the above initialize() function does not allow me to do cascading delete.

I need to manually modify initialize() like below to enable cascading delete. But this is cumbersome as the file gets overwritten every time with a new cake bake.

```
    $this->hasMany('BallRecords', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ball_id',
        //http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html
        //manually add the 2 lines below to enable cascading delete
        'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    ]);
```

Is there some way to configure cake bake to auto-generate code that manually enable cascading delete?

EDIT: A bounty was added to invite answers that configure bake templates.

Comment: Please see [Customizing the Bake Templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#customizing-the-bake-templates) in the manual. You can make them do anything that you want!

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately... No...

From Cake Back Model generator you can configure association with Cascading option.

You can check with help of cake bake model option by typing command `bin/cake bake model --help`

```
$ bin/cake bake model --help

Welcome to CakePHP v3.3.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: C:\wamp\www\student_logic\src\
PHP : 5.5.12
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake table and entity classes.

Usage:
cake bake.bake model [subcommand] [options] [<name>]

Subcommands:

all  Bake all model files with associations and validation.

To see help on a subcommand use `cake bake.bake model [subcommand] --help`

Options:

--help, -h             Display this help.
--verbose, -v          Enable verbose output.
--quiet, -q            Enable quiet output.
--plugin, -p           Plugin to bake into.
--force, -f            Force overwriting existing files without
                       prompting.
--connection, -c       The datasource connection to get data from.
                       (default: default)
--theme, -t            The theme to use when baking code.
                       (choices: Bake|Migrations)
--table                The table name to use if you have
                       non-conventional table names.
--no-entity            Disable generating an entity class.
--no-table             Disable generating a table class.
--no-validation        Disable generating validation rules.
--no-rules             Disable generating a rules checker.
--no-associations      Disable generating associations.
--no-fields            Disable generating accessible fields in the
                       entity.
--fields               A comma separated list of fields to make
                       accessible.
--no-hidden            Disable generating hidden fields in the entity.
--hidden               A comma separated list of fields to hide.
--primary-key          The primary key if you would like to manually set
                       one. Can be a comma separated list if you are
                       using a composite primary key.
--display-field        The displayField if you would like to choose one.
--no-test              Do not generate a test case skeleton.
--no-fixture           Do not generate a test fixture skeleton.

Arguments:

name  Name of the model to bake. Can use Plugin.name to bake plugin
      models. (optional)

Omitting all arguments and options will list the table names you can
generate models for
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. The problem is not with my model php file. I would like to configure cake bake such that the auto-generated php code by cake bake enables cascading delete by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Bad news but it's the truth. Hope the cakephp developers do something about it. Sigh ...

Comment: I dont know, who had down voted this answer.. I am very surprised.. if this option available in cake back let me know by comment.!!!

Comment: I upvoted and selected your answer as the answer. If there is good news, I would love to know too.

Comment: @user91579631, I know you have up voted.. but others some person down voting without any comment or reason.

Comment: Haresh Vidja, I have experienced that several times on Stack Overflow. Downvote without explanation. But most members don't do that. So, I am still very happy with the SO community. It will be nice if those who downvote can come out with better answers.

Comment: @user91579631, just I want to know you have unmark this answer from right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I set a bounty to attract answers that use bake templates to provide the solution. Your upvote remains.

Comment: @user91579631, ahh its okey :)

Comment: @user91579631, thanks for your bounty, please mark as correct again if you want. :)